# Canvas determine if point is on line

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to design a line chart which will show a tool tip when the user hovers over a line. Below is a minimal example showing my attempt at determining whether a point lies on a line (the line can be considered a rectangle with height 5 and width 80 in this case).

I don't understand why `isPointInPath` can only find the points at exactly the start and end points of the line. How can I determine if a point lies anywhere on the line?

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(100, 20);
ctx.stroke();
console.log(ctx.isPointInPath(20, 20)); // beginning: true
console.log(ctx.isPointInPath(100, 20)); // end: true
console.log(ctx.isPointInPath(60, 20)); // middle: false
console.log(ctx.isPointInPath(100, 21)); // end offset: false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isPointInPath` does use the fill region to make its check. You want [`isPointInStroke()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInStroke) which also takes the `lineWidth` into consideration:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const path = new Path2D();

let x = -1;
let y = -1;

for (let i = 0; i<20; i++) {
  path.lineTo(
    Math.random() * canvas.width, 
    Math.random() * canvas.height
  );
}

ctx.lineWidth = 5;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.isPointInStroke(path, x, y)
    ? "red"
    : "green";
  ctx.stroke(path);
}
draw();

addEventListener("mousemove", (evt) => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
  draw();
});
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

As to why `isPointInPath()` finds the points that are explicitly set in the Path declaration and not the ones that would logically lie on it... That's quite unclear I'm afraid, the specs don't have a clear *fill* algorithm, and I'll open a specs issue to fix that since there is actually an interop-issue with Safari acting as you'd expect, and Firefox + Chrome ignoring the fill area entirely when it doesn't produce a pixel, but still keeping these points.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function that tells you if a point is on a line with a width of 5px, we should use some analytical geometry: a point distance from a line. I copied formula from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points)

```js
function isPointOnLine(px, py, x1, y1, x2, y2, width) {

  return distancePointFromLine(px, py, x1, y1, x2, y2, width) <= width / 2
}

function distancePointFromLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return Math.abs((x2 - x1) * (y1 - y0) - (x1 - x0) * (y2 - y1)) / Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
}


const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
x1 = y1 = y2 = 20
x2 = 100
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(100, 20);
ctx.stroke();
console.log(isPointOnLine(20, 20, x1, y1, x2, y2, 5)); 
console.log(isPointOnLine(100, 20, x1, y1, x2, y2, 5)); 
console.log(isPointOnLine(60, 20, x1, y1, x2, y2, 5)); 
console.log(isPointOnLine(100, 21, x1, y1, x2, y2, 5));
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```